# Plone's captioned images source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plone

I use one of those jQuery libraries, [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), to make images show up in a modal pop-up style thing on top of the text. This works fine for mostly everything, however! When placing an image in TinyMCE and selecting "caption" and then making the image a link, the code Plone generates ends up having two of the same links, which result in a weird "Fancybox gallery slideshow" of the same image repeated twice. Here's why —

HTML from within TinyMCE:

```
<p><a class="internal-link" href="resolveuid/af2954f5af084d5aa359a480b33c5368" target="_self" title="Test test test"><img class="image-left captioned" src="resolveuid/af2954f5af084d5aa359a480b33c5368/@@images/image/med" /></a>
```

HTML generated when viewing the page:

```
<dl class="image-left captioned" style="width:300px;">
<dt>
<a class="internal-link" target="_self" href="http://127.0.0.1:8081/CAES/images/alison-king.jpg" title="Test test test" rel="gallery"><img width="300" height="200" title="alison king" alt="alison king" src="http://127.0.0.1:8081/CAES/images/alison-king.jpg/@@images/98443898-0834-45ea-b724-8f40a0c92e0c.jpeg"></a>
</dt>
<a class="internal-link" target="_self" href="http://127.0.0.1:8081/CAES/images/alison-king.jpg" title="Test test test" rel="gallery"><dd class="image-caption" style="width:300px;">test</dd>
```

I get why this happens and it's clever, but doesn't work for my purposes. Does anyone know where this code is generated in the ZMI? Or, any ideas on a jQuery solution to target all links except for that second one? Here's my existing Fancybox code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    /* Simple image gallery. Uses default settings */
    $("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();
  });
</script>
```

It will work with the following code, but then it only applies Fancybox to the first image link of a captioned image, and won't apply to any other non-captioned images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("dl.captioned dt a").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();
  });
</script>
```

And lastly, I tried to apply Fancybox to everything and then afterwards remove it from just the second dl.captioned link with jQuery, but can't quite get it, this still resu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif'],a[href$='/image']").attr('rel', 'gallery'); 
    $("dl.captioned > a").attr('rel', '');
    $("a[rel$='gallery']").fancybox();
  });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just after "a" tags containing images? Then $('a > img').parent() should do the selection.

Comment: Basically you have a screwed markup resulting of several JS, interfering each other. The second link doesn't have a closing tag, the definition-list is missing the definition-tag (dd). If this occurs in a lot of documents, you might need to manipulate the markup programatically. Could you please also post the markup saved in the document (hittin' the HTML-button in edit-mode), before JS-transformation is done? And are you using collective.fancybox?

Comment: Hi you two! So, I tried SteveM's method with parent(), but oddly enough it's not triggering Fancybox at all anymore. 

$('a > img').parent().attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();

It does add rel="gallery" but clicking on the link just goes to the image, no modal popup. I also tried this line without parent() just to see, and it worked once, but on closing the popup, the whole image disappears. Bizarre!

Comment: Also, my bad, the generated HTML output does have the closing tag and <dd> within that, but I must have miscopied it when writing above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot exactly reproduce the output you get, however can reproduce the doubled images in the gallery.

The doubling results, because the inserted image will be wrapped in a link to the image-file automagically (another JS, assumingly applied by TinyMCE), when you enable the captioning.

So, to resolve your request, it should be sufficient to NOT mark the images as links manually, when using the captioning anyway.

Nota: As you are using the `<script>`-tag, it seems you insert the JS in a template, yet it is recommended to embed it as a link in the header via JS-registration, especially, if you want this to happen globally. Alternatively add an expression-attribute in the registration, to restrict when the script should be delivered. If you have special reasons to only have this in a certain template, it is recommended to use the javascript-slot. Insert JS via a `<script>`-tag at the bottom of a document in order to execute it after the DOM is loaded, isn't necessary anymore, respectively discouraged, we can use document.ready (or window.onload) instead.

Steps I took to reproduce: Create a site, enable captioning via TinyMCE's controlpanel, install collective.fancybox, install a product of my own with a registered Javascript and insert:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Look for all links in content-area, 
        // add rel-attribute to make it a gallery.
        // Skipped distinction of whether it's an image or not, 'cause I'm
        // louzy lazy and you know how to DIY anyway ;)
        $("#content-core a").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Oh! You're totally right, removing the additional link (i.e. making the image a link) is an unnecessary step. I had thought this functionality was removed in a previous version of Plone, that marking an image captioned no longer made it a link as well, but apparently I was wrong. Thanks! — Also, we set up the <script> tag etc mainly for testing, but I always ran into problems using the internal portal_js registry, so I tend to serve our JS from our CDN and then attach them within our Diazo themes directly.

Comment: I also have a similar issue with the "News Image" that gets automatically attached when creating a News Item... I'll make that a separate question though. ;) Thanks again!!

Comment: No prob, that's what SO is for – ehm, not. That's where plone-users get directed when looking for support on plone.org... But anyway about the newsitem: I don't get the doubling with that one. Is it, you don't want newsitem's images in the gallery at all?

Comment: No, it's unrelated to the "doubling" issue — I can't seem to get Fancybox to work with a link that's "http://.../news-article/image" which is how Plone names the image that's attached to the News Item. So, the link is there but it just doesn't pop-up. Test example: http://www.caes.ucdavis.edu/news/articles/2013/12/sequencing-study-lifts-veil-on-wine2019s-microbial-terroir-1 — And the .js I was using is — $("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif'],a[href$='/image']").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();

Comment: Works for me, if I add 'image_view_fullscreen', which is the end of the URL in the the newsitem-template. In your example the url ends with 'image' only, have you done any customz to `newsitem_view`? BTW, I tested with P-4.1.6. Steve's suggestion works also, if you add a fitting selector (include "dd", "dl", or whatever) for the original prob (captioning and manual linking combined).

Comment: I made local copy of your example and added the class "fancybox.image" to the news-item's link, that works. Quoting the docs: "Script uses the `href` or `data-fancybox-href` attribute of the matched elements to obtain the location of the content and to figure out content type you want to display. You can specify type directly by adding classname (fancybox.image, fancybox.iframe, etc)"

Comment: Explanation: The MIME-Type coudn't be recognized, which you probably wanted to achieve with the class "fancybox-media". I tried with "fancybox.media", then the overlay pops up, yet no content, which confirms the MIME-Type issue.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right! I must have edited the newsitem_view before. I switched it back to 'image_view_fullscreen' and can def get the pop-up working now. I also added the "fancybox.image" (you mean, to the link that contains the news image, correct?), however I get this error: http://cl.ly/image/1P3X161m2E0d — any thoughts? Maybe I have the wrong version of Fancybox?

Comment: Leave everything like it was and only apply the class "fancybox.image" to the link. If that doesn't work, I think it's time to open a new quest ;) [Nota: The dots in the class-name are against the naming conventions.]

Comment: Nailed it! That's excellent, thanks so much Ida! If I ever catch you at a Plone event, remind be to buy you several beers. :)

Comment: Hey Ida, I'm going to make a new SO question for this because I think it'd be useful for anyone with the same problem. You can copy & paste your answer over to here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555635/get-fancybox-to-cooperate-with-plones-news-item-image